# access to the path is denied C#

Tags: c#, file-io, io

When I am running the application I can access the file..
When I am running the executable that is created, I cannot access the file..
Any suggestions?

The error I am getting is :
access to the path 'E:\Javascript.js' is denied.

Comment: I think more detail is needed to understand your problem.  Do you mean that it works in Visual Studio debug but fails when you run the exe directly?  What's the exact error number/message?

Comment: "the file"? Which file? "the application"? Which application? "the executable that is created"? Which executable? Created how? What is the error message you get?

Comment: What filepath do you access? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Are you attempting to run both at the same time? You might be competing for a shared file.

Comment: I do not have enough information to answer this question.

Comment: Lasse, "the file" is just any text-file. "the application" is the application I am running. "the executable that is created" is the executable that is created when you create a console application..

Comment: Daniel, it's exactly what you said that I mean! :)
I don't have an error number :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the user permissions for the path & exe.

Here's how: [Source](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/security/permissions.mspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would check:

1. The permissions the executable is running under.
2. The path to the file is correct (it's not accidentally using a relative path).

Comment: I checked the permissions and they seem ok.
The path is correct (double checked).

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions for an executable sometimes depend on where the executable is located (e.g., a network share vs. local hard drive) and where it came from (e.g., downloaded from the Internet). Check the properties of the executable file.

You should also check Control Panel->Administrative Tools->.Net Framework 2.0 Configuration->Configure Code Access Security Policy.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the file?
Are you executing it or are you reading it?
If you're reading it, what filemode and sharemodes are you using?
Is it possible that some other process has an open handle to the file (a previous instance of your application that's still running perhaps, or the editor used to create the file)?